# Increase Ground Plane Grid Size

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everyone, I know that you can adjust the size of the ground plane itself, but is there a way to change the size of the gridded area so it's bigger than 20x20? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6673/increase-ground-plane-grid-size/) by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 103 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I know that the plane geometry tag has a size parameter (see [ground_plane model](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/a8fbd980b60ce207db3fd579956241e873ef7861/ground_plane/model.sdf)), but it's actually ignored for physics purposes in ODE and is actually an infinite ground plane. The size is used for the visual, which can be seen when you zoom out.

Regarding the grid, that is not a property of the ground plane, but actually a rendering property of the scene. The following tag can be used to disable the grid: `<grid>false</grid>` (see [blank.world](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/8d6519e28f009539dfe52e4f8ec135c699f4658e/worlds/blank.world?at=default)) or it can be toggled from the `View -> Grid` menu.

The size of the grid is currently hard-coded in [gazebo::rendering::Scene::SetGrid](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/8d6519e28f009539dfe52e4f8ec135c699f4658e/gazebo/rendering/Scene.cc?at=default#cl-2761).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-07-23**:
Thank you very much for the answer! Is there a way to access SetGrid.cc so I can change the grid size?? I tried to find a copy of that code on my harddrive, but all I found was SetGrid.hh, which appears to only list the functions, not the functions themselves?

**Comment by [IsaacS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/15/isaacs/) on 2015-06-22**:
In my application I replaced planes with boxes, with their width = 0.01. I don't know if that's appropriate but seems to be working fine for my purpose (I just needed stairs).